# Creating a grid with different color vertices (graph)

Tags: conditionals, graphs, tkz-berge

I am new to using tikz and I have never used ifthenelse statements in latex before, but I am trying to create a grid where the vertices on every other diagonal are a different color and shape. This is what I have now, based on what I found at https://graphtheoryinlatex.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/edges-on-a-grid/

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \grGrid[prefix=a,RA=1.5,RB=1.5]{8}{8}
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}{
     \foreach \y in {0,1,...6}{
         %something ifthenelse to change vertices
     }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you not complete the given code snippet (leaving the colors out) to show us what you have. Then we can better help you. Now it is only guessing what you want ...  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements on diagonals have either odd or even sum of indexes, so you can use `\ifodd`; schematically:

```
\ifodd\numexpr\Row+\Column\relax
   do domething for elements on diagonals with odd sum of indexes
\else
   do domething for elements on diagonals with even sum of indexes
\fi
```

In the question it's not clear if `tkz-berge` is really needed so I opted for a "pure" TikZ approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
\def\Factor{1.4}
\foreach \Column in {1,...,8}
{
  \foreach \Row in {1,...,8}
  {
    \ifodd\numexpr\Row+\Column\relax
      \def\Shape{circle}
      \def\Color{cyan!40}
    \else
      \def\Shape{rectangle}
      \def\Color{red!40}
    \fi
    \node[
      minimum size=1cm,
      shape=\Shape,
      fill=\Color,
      font=\footnotesize,
      ] 
      (a\Column\Row)
      at (\Factor*\Row,-\Factor*\Column) 
      {a\Column,\Row};
  }
}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw (a11) grid[step=\Factor] (a88);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Solves my problem and I can learn more from it for the future! :)